# EXC_BAD_ACCESS fatal error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have got this code which creates an image:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 60, 180, 180)];
result = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 60, 180, 180)];
[background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]]];
[self.view addSubview:background];
[self.view insertSubview:result aboveSubview:background];
```

This is in my `viewWillAppear`. When I press a button, this happens:

```
- (IBAction)oneToSix {
int rNumber = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
[result setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", rNumber]]];
}
```

But it gets this fatal error: `Thread one: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".` on the `setImage` part when I press the button. What is the problem? I am new to Objective C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is string format in NSString, you should change the code to :

```
[result setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber]]];
```

as rNumber is an int.

And you should release the background and result, as viewWillAppear will tend to be called every time the view is appear so will result a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have Xcode 4.2 with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). Do I still have to release them?

Comment: Will it release on `viewWillDisappear` when using ARC?

Comment: yes it will, try read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work