# Config file in xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5, configuration-files

I m new to iphone development and I want to know what is `config file` in xcode(iphone and ipad) similar to the one like `Androidmanifest.xml` in andriod.

Where can I find good tutorials to change settings for `differnt apps(like change app name ,app themes for different apps)` in `config file` and do I need to generate it ?

Any help would be highly appreciated....

Comment: You can read this url

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182026/ios-application-configuration-file

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary it is not storing small amount of data.I want to create different apps with different names but with same code.So I want to change it in config file.I want to now what would be the extension of such file.???

Answer (score 0):

Here in this screen shot you can see yourProjectName-Info.plist. there you can find more option to setting your project.

[image]