# iOS - using multiple connections

Tags: ios4

I've got a simple login view that when you successfully log in, it goes and fetches some json from a server and inserts it into a database. So im using:

```
// NSURLRequest 

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // appending data
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // insert into db
}
```

I want a second connection now to download some documents, how can I utilise the methods above to pass it another URL and handle data in a different manner (not json) for the 2nd NSURLRequest in the same view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing you need to do is set the `delegate` of your new `NSURLConnection` to this class again, so the methods get called (but you knew that). If you're doing these one at a time, store a pointer to the active `NSURLRequest`, something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSURLRequest *activeURLRequest;
```

Then check the active request's URL to differentiate the requests:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *urlPath = [[activeURLRequest URL] path];
    if([urlPath isEqualToString:@"http://my.url.string/1"])
        // insert into DB
    else if([urlPath isEqualToString:@"http://my.url.string/2"])
        // do the other thing
}
```

Note you can also compare the `NSURL` object directly with a stored version of it using `isEqual:` (or the `==` operator).

If you're doing more than one at a time, you need another way to differentiate. I recommend using [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to make this easier, but if you want to do it using Apple's libraries then you'll need to spin off multiple threads, keep a record of which thread number is handling which request URL, and use that information in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll play with this active URL idea and process information according the URL. I didn't want to use ASIHTTPRequest (which is great) but I think it's not being supported anymore? i.e. no IOS5 updates for example. Cheers.

Comment: I agree `ASIHTTPRequest` isn't being supported anymore, but that doesn't mean it's broken. It still works great for me, there's a lot of finnicky thread-safe coding in there which has been refined over the years. It's also the simplest way to cache particular requests on disk in a custom location (that I've seen) and it handles HTTP redirects very well.

Comment: do you have any issues with ASIHTTPRequest for iOS5? I remember doing a build and it was throwing ghastly warnings of which I had no idea about.

Comment: I'm using it in an `iOS5`-compatible app which is in the App Store right now. It's used for both retrieving (and caching) XML requests, and as a download manager/storage framework. No issues. Of course, I'm not using `ARC`; it'd need to be reworked a bit if you enabled that.

Comment: I will need to look at it again. I'm not sure what ARC is so I'll have to check that. I just need it to be able to download json and files asynchronously and so Apple's libraries may get to complex if ASIHTTPRequest can do it for me.

Comment: ARC is mostly explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work). If you don't need caching, I'd say go with `AFNetworking` instead. It already contains a `JSON` component. Link in the answer.