# What is Automatic Reference Counting?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

What is Automatic Reference Counting?
i am new iPhone developer.
thanks in advance..

Comment: http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/

Comment: Did you even google this before posting here?

Comment: this link will help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had asked the same question to [WIKI](http://www.wikipedia.org) , the first line you would see is

**In Objective-C programming, Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is a memory management enhancement where the burden of keeping track of an object's reference count is lifted from the programmer to the compiler.**

That includes everything you need to understand as a beginner. You can see the complete description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting)

And, next, if you want to know **How ARC works?**, I don't think you could see anything better than [Brad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418410/1756131) here.

Answer (score 0):

ARC is automatic reference counting. Prior to ARC we use manual release/retain/autorelease calls for memory management But Apple has introduced ARC to remove this manual memory management.

Here is a good tutorial of **[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)**

And to understand ARC you should have some knowledge of [**Memory Management**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i)

Answer (score 0):

Automatic reference counting (ARC) was introduced in the iOS 5 sdk to free Objective-C programmers from having to handle memory management by making memory management the job of the compiler.

If you developer with Objective-C prior to the iOS 5 SDK or talked to Obj-C programmers then you are probably aware of how tedious task memory management could become.  When using ARC there is no need for retain and release calls, and not only that in many cases ARC can provide a significant performance increase.