# How is ARC in Swift different from garbage collector in Java?

Tags: java, c++, swift

I am relatively new to memory management concepts and having programmed a little bit in Java, C++ and Swift, I was curious about the differences between the memory management techniques used by each.

From what I know in Java and Swift, objects can only be created on the heap memory. When the object is out of scope, the reference is magically removed. How does this work? I kinda understand how it works in C++, but I would really appreciate if you could shed some light on how memory management works in Java and Swift.

Answer (score 2):

For a good introduction to how reference counting differs from garbage collection, see:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285333/how-does-garbage-collection-compare-to-reference-counting

For how Swift does this automatically, see:

[How does the new automatic reference counting mechanism work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work)