# How do I replace weak references when using ARC and targeting iOS 4.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I've begun developing my first iOS app with Xcode 4.2, and was targeting iOS 5.0 with a "utility application" template (the one that comes with a FlipsideViewController).

I read that since ARC is a compile-time feature, it should be compatible with iOS 4 as well, so I attempted to target my app to 4.3, and try compiling it. When I do so, I get this error:

**FlipsideViewController.m: error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: The current deployment target does not support automated __weak references**

It is referencing this line:

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

That variable is declared as:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

I understand that "weak references" are not supported in iOS 4, but I don't really understand why I would want to use a weak reference to begin with, nor can I figure out how I would rewrite things to avoid using it, while still taking advantage of ARC (after all, it's supposed to work with iOS 4 AND 5 right?)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

To target the older OS, you can use `unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak` in your property declaration, and it should mostly work the same way.  `weak` references nil themselves when their target goes away, but `unsafe_unretained` leaves open the possibility that the object you're linking to could turn into a dangling pointer when it is deallocated.  The latter is the same behavior as if you had used `assign` as a property declaration in manual memory management.

You do this to avoid retain cycles, which I mention in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-objective-cs-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-4-2/6388601#6388601).  You don't want to have a strong pointer to something that might have a strong pointer back to the original object.  Then nothing would get released properly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You say "to target the older OS...". Does this mean I should only use unsafe_unretained in builds of the app older than 5.0? Or can I just use unsafe_unretained in my code, and build it to target both 4.x and 5.x?

Comment: @Mason - `unsafe_unretained` is supported in both iOS 4.x and 5.0, so it gives you backwards compatibility.  If you were doing a 5.0-only build, you might switch to `weak` to take advantage of the additional safety it gives you.

Comment: I tried unsafe_unretained, it worked anyway. However, I got lot's of warning like '"** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x564bd90 of class __NSArrayM autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking"* ', that's normal?

Comment: @fifth - That's a totally unrelated issue. You're running something on a background thread without having an autorelease pool in place. Manually created threads do not have their own autorelease pool, so you need to create one yourself using `@autoreleasepool` (under ARC, NSAutoreleasePool for older manually reference counted implementations).

Comment: @Brad, that's helpful, warnings're gone, I got several performSelectorInBackground calls.

Comment: @fifth - As a suggestion, you should really look at moving to blocks and GCD. Blocks dispatched on a background queue have an autorelease pool already in place for you, but more than that GCD can simplify your code and make your multithreading much more efficient.

Comment: @Stunner - Your edit wasn't correct. Property attributes do not have the underscores that you edited into my answer. Those only apply to instance variables.

Comment: @BradLarson My mistake, was using it for variables and realized it wasn't working. Figured you happened to overlook that so I made an edit.

Answer (score 11):

If only using weak references for additional safety, manually call the new runtime functions if they're available and fallback to simple assignment on `__unsafe_unretained` variables if not.

[ZWRCompatibility.h](https://github.com/rpetrich/ZWRCompatibility) will simplify this somewhat.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Mike Ash's compatibility library [PLWeakCompatibilty](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility), you can now simply use __weak on iOS 4.x, as well.

It's incredibly easy to configure and requires no additional consideration or effort over 5.x.