# Memory Leak issue iOS

Tags: ios, object, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have a memory leak spawning from the block below. Im pretty certain the following objects are getting tangled up. I have tried setting them up with (weak) relationships but that hasn't been successful. Any ideas on how I could combat/rewrite this issue? Thanks.

```
AssistHub.m

 @implementation

- (void)startGameWithBlock:(void (^)(Game *))block
{

     _viewControllerGame = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
     _viewControllerGame.delegate = (id)self;

     Game *game = [[Game alloc] init];
     _viewControllerGame.thisGame = game;
     game.delegate = _viewControllerGame;

     block(game);

}
```

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707143/can-using-weak-attribute-to-pass-parameter-to-blocks-lead-to-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0):

Please, do the following checks:

1. First ensure you use weak references if required to avoid memory retain cycles. Please see the following link that could help you to write weak reference in a more consice way  [weak references](http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html).
2. Be sure that you're using ***weak*** for your delegates too. If not, you'd be causing a cycle there too. Check **_viewControllerGame.delegate** and **+game.delegate = _viewControllerGame;***