# Discovering at runtime which of a class' instance variables are declared __weak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm writing a tool which would benefit from knowing which of a class' instance variables are declared `__weak`.

This information must exist *somewhere* at runtime, but is there any way of accessing it, documented or otherwise? (It's for a tool, so I don't care so much about it breaking with updates)

Comment: This question has caught my fancy, so if you don't get a response, don't worry, I'm working on it

Comment: Does it matter if the iVar is `unsafe_unretained` vs `weak`? If not, that makes my life much easier.

Comment: strong vs not strong is the distinction I'm interested in.

Comment: awesome. Then give me 5-10 minutes to throw together an answer, and you'll be golden!

Comment: Ok, new update. Can determine between `weak` and `strong`, but for whatever reason `__unsafe_unretained` seems to be acting like `strong`. More time is needed.

Comment: I'd have expected __weak / not weak is all that's left at runtime. The distinction between __unsafe_unretained and strong is all effected at compile-time, right?

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking that that is the problem. I can submit my current findings now, with the caveat that __unsafe_unretained throws your code into a hell-hole, or I can search for another solution. Your move.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to see it. If nothing else, it might give me an idea or two...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14310/discussion-between-cxd-and-richard-j-ross-iii)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, here is a sample implementation, using a custom object implementation, that does a rudimentary check to see if an iVar is weak or not:

```
BOOL iVarIsWeak(Class cls, Ivar ivar)
{
    id classInstance = [cls new];

    // our custom base class properly tracks reference counting, no weird voodoo
    id refCounter = [CustomBaseClass new];

    object_setIvar(classInstance, ivar, refCounter);

    if ([refCounter refCount] == 2)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The above code is meant to be used with ARC enabled, while the following custom object code is not:

```
@interface CustomBaseClass : NSObject

+(id) new;
+(id) alloc;
-(id) init;

-(id) retain;
-(void) release;
-(id) autorelease;
-(void) dealloc;

-(id) description;

-(unsigned) refCount;

@end


// easy way to get sizeof
struct CustomBaseClassAsStruct {
    voidPtr isa;
    unsigned volatile refcount;
};

@implementation CustomBaseClass
{
    unsigned volatile  refcount;
}

+(id) new
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

+(id) alloc
{
    struct CustomBaseClassAsStruct *results =  malloc(sizeof(struct CustomBaseClassAsStruct));
    results->isa = self;
    results->refcount = 0;
    return (id) results;
}

-(id) init
{
    [self retain];

    return self;
}

-(id) retain
{
    ++refcount;

    return self;
}

-(void) release
{
    if (--refcount == 0)
        [self dealloc];
}

-(id) autorelease
{
    // sample implementation of autorelease
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        [self release];
    });

    return self;
}

-(unsigned) refCount
{
    return refcount;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    free(self);

    // no call to [super dealloc], we are using custom memory-managment
}

@end
```

This ONLY works for weak iVars. With a `unsafe_unretained` variable, it will give a false positive, my best guess for this is because `__weak` information is saved at runtime whilst `unsafe_unretained` information is not.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting. I'd thought that the runtime only needed information about storage in order to zero out weak references when deallocating, but I hadn't considered that object_setIvar would need it too (although it makes sense given that object_setInstanceVariable is banned under ARC). It probably should treat `__unsafe_unretained` similarly to `__weak`. I'll file a bug.