# iOS: Reference counting

Tags: ios

I am doing some research on reference count increase. Please help on finding it.
Below is sample code and research i'm doing what would happen of reference counting for each line below.

.h file

```
NSArray *tempArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tempArray;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize tempArray;

    -(void) sampleFunction
{
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // Thinking reference count increases to "1"
    tempArray = myArray;// reference count increases and tempArray gets retain count "1" now.
    tempArray = myArray;// reference count increases and tempArray gets retain count "2" now.
    tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"SomeString"]; // retain count = ?

}
```

I know this code may not be for functioning, but this is for only researching about what will happen on reference counting for such scenarios. I tried printing retainCount, but it doesn't show the correct result. Please advise me how does the reference count works on this each line?

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Read about `retainCount` in the `NSObject Protocol Reference`.

Comment: `tempArray = myArray;` doesn't quite increase you retain count. Only `self.tempArray = myArray;` would.

Comment: @H2CO3, You seem to have jumped to conclusions here; there is no mention to the method `retainCount`, only the underlying idea of retain count and a form of memory management.

Comment: @JamesWebster only if you had read the question... " I tried printing retainCount, but it doesn't show the correct result"

Comment: Exactly, the OP learned that retainCount wasn't a viable option.

Comment: Hi, There are many answers here, Can i conclude that, (i) if i use variable @property with 'retain' and try to set some value into it for ex: myArray, it won't retain the count? My question is, why would say when we 'retain' the reference count increases? Is it not applicable when using via @property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lines 2, 3 and 4 you are affecting the instance variable `tempArray` to the same object as `myArray`.  But if you write it this way, you try to affect an instance variable. As a matter of fact, if you didn't write any `@synthesize tempArray` or `@synthesize tempArray = tempArray` in your code, by default the instance variable generated automatically to store the property value is the same name as the property name, but prefixed with an underscore. So as the property name is `tempArray`, the instance variable is named `_tempArray`. The instance variable `tempArray` itself does not exist and your line of code is invalid.

So if we suppose you wrote instead:

```
-(void) sampleFunction
{
  NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // (1)
  self.tempArray = myArray; // (2)
  self.tempArray = myArray; // (3)
  self.tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"SomeString"]; // (4)
}
```

- In (1) you are creating a brand new instance of NSArray. "alloc" always initialize new instance with a reference count of 1
- In (2) you write `self.tempArray = myArray` (which is equivalent to `[self setTempArray:myArray];` and thus call the property setter), so you set the property to point to the same array you created in (1). This array is thus retained by the property, and its retainCount increses by one, because it is retained by `myArray` and by the `self.tempArray` property.
- In (3) you affect the property to the very same object as before. This the ref count does not change at all. You could understand that as if you replaced the value of the `self.tempArray` with another value, so the setter of the property release the old value (decrementing its ref count), then retain the new value (thus incrementing its ref count). As in your case the old and new values are the same object, you would decrement the ref count of your array then re-increment it again. In practice, the ref count does not even change at all (instead of decrementing+incrementing again) to avoid any potential dealloc of the object, because the default implementation of a property setter is as follow:

  ```
  -(void)setTempArray:(NSArray*)newValue
  {
    // check if old and new value are different. Only do sthg if they are different
    if (newValue != _tempArray)
    {
      [_tempArray release];  // release old value
      [newValue retain];     // retain new value
      _tempArray = newValue; // store new value in the backing variable associated with the property
    }
  }
  ```
- In (4) you replace again the value of the property `tempArray`, but this time with a completely new object. So the property will release its old value and retain the new one. Thus the first array you created in (1) which had a refcount of 2 (retained by `myArray` and by `self.tempArray`) decrease its ref count to 1 (because the property won't retain it anymore), and the new instance you created `[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"SomeString"]` is retained by the property, so its ref count is +1.

---

If you replaced `self.tempArray = ...` (so the use of the property) with the direct use of the instance variable, using instance variables don't retain the objects they are affected to (except if you are using ARC but it seems you don't), so the ref count of the object wouldn't have changed at all in (2), (3) and (4).

Comment: Hi, There are many answers here, Can i conclude that, (i) if i use variable @property with 'retain' and try to set some value into it for ex: myArray, it won't retain the count? My question is, why would say when we 'retain' the reference count increases? Is it not application when using via @property?

Comment: That's what we explained in our answers : if you assign a value to a `@property(retain)` it **will** retain the value it is assigned to (and release the old value it was pointing to before the assignation, if any). So it will increase the retainCount. You shouldn't really think about the retain count directly, but rather in terms of who retains your object. A `@property(retain)` retains the object it is affected to (and release it when it is no longer affected to it)

Comment: Ok,please give some example how reference count increases when we are using 'retain' in a @property variable. So, my doubt will be cleared completely. You have also mentioned it will not increase the retain count in steps (2), (3) and (4). So, i don't know whether retain count will be increment or not if we are using property (retain).

Comment: I gave it already in my original answer (as soon as my first code snippet). It **WILL** increase the retain count of your array in (2). But not in 3 (because it will increase it and then decrease the one of the object previously pointed by the property… which is the same `myArray`, so it goes +1 -1). In (4), it will decrease the refcount of your first array and increase the one of the other array. Read my answer again, that's exactly what I explained.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `retain count` increase only in new, alloc, retain and copy condition but if we are providing ownership to an object through this for `retain count` will increase other than that there is no possibility to increase `retain count`.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, [don't even try to rely upon retainCount.](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

After that: you're wondering which scenario happens among the ones you enumerated. Well, **neither one.**

Why? Because, in first palce, you're assigning to an instance variable directly - that won't change retain count. At all. Except if you use ARC, but it seems you don't.

You probably wanted to assign stuff to the *property* of the object, that is, write

```
self.tempArray = myArray;
```

etc. Now because the *property* itself (and **not** its backing ivar!) is declared as `retain`, the corresponding accessor method will increase the reference count of the *object being assigned to the property.* However, in order not to leak memory, an accessor method is usually implemented by releasing the previously assigned object when assigning and thus retaining the new one, i. e.

```
- (void)setTempArray:(NSArray *)tmp
{
    [tmp retain];
    [tempArray release];
    tempArray = tmp;
}
```

So basically, when you reassign `myArray` to the `self.tempArray` property, it looses and gains a reference, thus its reference count doesn't chnage at all.

When you assign another, new array to the property, then again `myArray` loses a refcount, dropping to 0 it is deallocated, then the new array, created using `+ [NSArray arrayWithObject:]` is retained. Its exact reference count is supposed to be 1 after this, since it was created using `alloc - init - autorelease` (that's how the method is implemented), and it has been retained by the property. However, the value returned by `- retainCount` is still (and never) to be relied upon.

Comment: Good old `retainCount`. Actually, in some **VERY** specific situations, when you KNOW exactly what is happening, it is OK, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621028/discovering-at-runtime-which-of-a-class-instance-variables-are-declared-weak/11621650#11621650. As a general practice, no, though.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that answer of yours uses something called `refCount` and not `retainCount`.

Comment: Look at the implementation, and you'll see that it's little more than a wrapper for `retainCount` which can be used in ARC code.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I couldn't spot `retainCount` anywhere in the implementation, `- refCount` just returns the ivar named `refcount`. Also, in `+ alloc`, why are you initially setting the reference count to 0? Should it not be 1?

Comment: @H2C03 `refCount` is set to `1` in `init`, not `alloc` in my sample implementation. There's no major distinction there.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I see. (btw it's an O not a 0 :)

Comment: Hi, There are many answers here, Can i conclude that, (i) if i use variable @property with 'retain' and try to set some value into it for ex: myArray, it won't retain the count? My question is, why would say when we 'retain' the reference count increases? Is it not applicable when using via @property?

Comment: @userxxx it is applicable for the property, but you're not using the property here. You're setting the instance variables directly, which is something completely different.

Comment: Ok,please give some example how reference count increases when we are using 'retain' in a @property variable. So, my doubt will be cleared completely.

Comment: @userXXX `self.someRetainedProperty = anObject;`

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, you are assigning to `tempArray` directly and not `self.tempArray`, so the `retainCount` will stay at 1 throughout. But let's go through what would happen if you did what I think you meant.

In objective-c, a synthesized retained property will have a setter functionally equivalent to this:

```
-(void) setTempArray:(NSArray *value)
{
    if(tempArray != value) {
        [tempArray release];
        tempArray = [value retain];
    }
}
```

This increases the retain count when a new object is assigned to it, essentially does nothing when it is set to the same object, and releases it when something else is assigned to it.  So the retain counts in your example go something like this:

```
-(void) sampleFunction
{
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // Retain count of 1
    self.tempArray = myArray; // 2
    self.tempArray = myArray; // still 2
    self.tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"SomeString"]; 
    // myArray.retainCount is 1,
    // tempArray.retainCount is 2 but with 1 autorelease
    // myArray leaks
}
```

Comment: No. `retainCount` won't most probably stay 1.

Comment: He's assigning to the ivar directly, that won't affect the retain count in the slightest.

Comment: I did, you say precisely the same thing I do - assigning to the ivar doesn't change the retainCount but assigning to the property does. And technically, you're incorrect in saying the retainCount drops to 0 at the last release, if it's released with a retainCount of 1 it's deallocated without bothering to decrement the count.

Comment: nope. One, it's not `retainCount` but the reference count of the object. `retainCount` returns a number that is mostly unrelated to what the actual reference count is. Don't use these two expressions interchangeably because they're not equivalent. Two. In theory, an object is deallocated when its reference count reaches 0, and not when it reaches 1.

Comment: The docs say `- (NSUInteger)retainCount
Return Value

The receiver’s reference count.` Apple's own documentation uses them interchangeably, and for the purposes of understanding the `retain`/`release`/`autorelease` cycle, And I'm in no way advocating their use, and the OP is not saying anything about actually using them either. And you misunderstood my point about deallocating. When the retain count hits 1, nothing happens. When it is already 1 and `release` is called (i.e. it would be 1 if it were updated), it is deallocated. Without bothering to actually decrement the variable.

Comment: Hi, There are many answers here, Can i conclude that, (i) if i use variable @property with 'retain' and try to set some value into it for ex: myArray, it won't retain the count? My question is, why would say when we 'retain' the reference count increases? Is it not application when using via @property?

Comment: If you use `self.array = myArray` and `array` is declared `retain`, it will retain `myArray`.  But if you just use `array = myArray` that won't retain it. `self` is important - and that's why you should use `_` for your ivars (or let clang autosynthesize them), to avoid this confusion.