# __unsafe_unretained NSString struct var

Tags: iphone, ios, struct, nsstring

I am trying to create a structure that has several different variable of different types in it.

several of the types are of NSString, but trying to do this was causing an error

`ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions`

so having read about the error I see its sensible to add

```
__unsafe_unretained
```

before the NSString declaration, However I have no idea what the ramifications of this will be, I have had a quick read around and found this detailed [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593731/748343) about the differences of

- __strong
- __weak
- __unsafe_unretained

however it was still abit vague about whats going on with a NSString thats in a struct with __unsafe_unretained infront of it and was hoping someone can tell me whats going on and what I need to think about in the future regarding memory and stopping any leaks.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ARC - The meaning of __unsafe_unretained?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592289/arc-the-meaning-of-unsafe-unretained)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose, under ARC, you could declare a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    __strong NSObject *someObject;
    int someInteger;
} MyStruct;
```

Then you might write code like this:

```
MyStruct *thing = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
```

Problem: `malloc` doesn't zero-fill the memory it returns.  So `thing->someObject` is some random value - not necessarily NULL.  Then you assign a value to it like this:

```
thing->someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Under the covers, ARC will turn that into code like this:

```
NSObject *temporary = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[thing->someObject release];
thing->someObject = temporary;
```

The problem here is that your program just sent `release` to some random value!  Your app will probably crash at this point.

You might say that ARC should recognize the call to `malloc` and take care of setting `someObject` to NULL to prevent this.  The problem is that `malloc` might be wrapped in some other function, like this:

```
void *myAllocate(size_t size) {
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (!p) {
        // malloc failed.  Try to free up some memory.
        clearCaches();
        p = malloc(size);
    }
    return p;
}
```

OK, now ARC has to know about your `myAllocate` function too... and that might be inside some static library that you got as a binary.

Your app might even have its own memory allocators that recycle old allocations without using `free` and `malloc` every time.  So even changing `malloc` to zero-fill the memory before returning it would not work.  ARC would have to know about any custom allocators in your program.

It would be very, very hard to make this work reliably.  So instead, the creators of ARC just gave up and said “Forget it.  We're not going to let you put `__strong` and `__weak` references in structs.”

That's why you can only put an object pointer into a struct if you use `__unsafe_unretained` to tell ARC “Don't try to manage ownership of the object that this references.”

You can try to use a struct containing `__unsafe_unretained` object references, perhaps using `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` to manually retain and release them.  Then you can create an array of such structs.  This is error-prone, so you should only do it if the profiler tells you that it's critical for performance.

Instead, just create a new Objective-C class instead of a struct.  Give the class an `@property` for each field you would have put in the struct.  The use an `NSMutableArray` to manage an array of instances of this new class.

Comment: Well, ARC is actually built into the language, whereas malloc is just a lowly library function.  Who's breaking whom? ;->

Comment: @JodyHagins I worry about that question a little too much... And besides, if malloc fails, the general response is to quit, run and hide in a corner until that wormhole you just created goes away.

Comment: lol... cool, thanks for your response, I understand my mistake now. the funny thing is I actually created a new Object class and tried to declare a struct in it.. lol I know what I need to do I loose it with the execution.. which I am trying to figure out by reading lots then presenting issues I am stuck with to helpfull people such as yourself on stakoverflow.

Comment: You can actually just use `-retain` & `-release` on an `__unsafe_unretained` pointer, it's one of the weird quirks of ARC.

Comment: Ownership qualifiers are for the pointers not the types, so use it that way `NSString * __string aString`. Apple allows the other way but advises **not** to write it that way, because it is simply wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Just more food for thought...

If you really need ARC pointers in non-objective-c code, you can use them natively in C++.

In fact, you can store ARC pointers in all the standard template containers, and they still retain (ha ha) their proper semantics.

```
struct Foo {
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    NSString *string;
    __weak UIViewController *viewController;
};

std::list<UIView*> views;
```

Since the compiler treats ARC pointers as objects with non-trivial constructors, they can have their normal semantics.

All their ARC glory will be magically handled.

Comment: ha ha indeed! :P  rhank you very much :) but I think for my own sake I should stick with Objective C class objects. however thank you for helping with my understanding of the situation.. I am still reading through your guys comments looking up the meaning of some of the tearms you are using I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 2):

ARC just loves to complain!  Actually, we have to look at this historically.  In the old-style Manual Reference Counted environment from way back, the compiler didn't complain because it knew everything memory related was going to be your job, and your job alone.  But that changed when Apple introduced Automatic Reference Counting, because the compiler needed to get substantially more anal about what type an object was and what it was contained in, so that it knew how to properly manage the memory for said object efficiently.  When you place an Objective-C object into a C-struct, you're sort of sticking out your tongue at the compiler because a struct implies that you will own and manage the memory of the items inside of it yourself (that and ARC doesn't touch malloc and free).  That's where `__unsafe_unretained` comes in.  With it, we tell the compiler that any and all memory operations will be your responsibility, just like in MRC.  ARC literally "can't guarantee the safety" of the object's pointer being nil after deallocation, so it makes you explicitly declare it as such.

If you want to avoid all of this nonsense, just make your struct into a lightweight class and declare your objects normally.  After all, classes in Objective-C are just C-structs-(ish) with a lot of Apple magic thrown in.

Comment: Classes are not “just C-structs with a little Apple magic thrown in.”  Under the modern runtime, they are not structs at all.

Comment: So what are classes if not a (complicated) struct (id, objc_class, isa, @defs) then?

Comment: okay cool.. so really what I should do is create a lightweight class that just stores values. this can then be the object of an array in another class that can handle all the methods that will sort the array. Dose that make sense to you?

Comment: You'd probably want a controller type of object.  One that manages the array, instead of the array managing itself.  Subclass NSObject.

Comment: @CodaFi Read about [non-fragile ivars](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html).  Especially the “How it works” section at the end.

Comment: OK, but how is this not Apple magic operating on a struct?  Perhaps "Apple" and "Compiler" should be synonyms?

Comment: @rob while that may be the case sometimes, you can still actually create a strict with a `isa` pointer as it's first member and you can be darned sure that it will work just fine as an objective C object.. Where things get weird is subclassing.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII You can get a block of memory any way you want, put a class reference in its first four bytes, then cast the pointer to an object pointer.  So what?  I could do that with a union.  Is a class therefore a union?  I could do it with a carefully-crafted `float` or `double`.  Is a class therefore a floating-point type?

Comment: @CodaFi I can create a struct-typed variable on the stack, but  I can't create a class instance on the stack.  I can use `offsetof` on a struct field, but I can't use it on a class instance variable.  I can create an array of structs (e.g. `MyStruct *p = malloc(10 * sizeof *p)`), but I can't create an array of instances.  When I access a struct field, the compiler generates code that hardcodes the field offset at compile time, but when I access an instance variable, the compiler generates code that looks up the field offset at runtime.  How exactly is a class a struct?

Comment: I can use `sizeof` on a struct, but I can't use `sizeof` on an instance.  I can embed a struct in another struct, but I can't embed a class in a struct or another class (except by subclassing).

Comment: I feel like we're all talking past each other.  Surely we all know about the basic definition of an objc object being just a typdef'd pointer to a struct (id).  But then again, the compiler offers up lots of little changes and tweaks, as you mention, which sets classes apart from structs (else what would be the point of @interfaces?).  And Rich is right.  Even NSObject keeps an isa pointer.

Comment: The modern runtime uses a C-ism for convenience and perhaps backward-compatibility; that doesn't mean a class *is* a struct.  I have written code that defines a struct with bitfields for convenient direct access to the sign, exponent, and mantissa of a double.  Does that mean that a double is a struct?

Comment: Now if I had actually said a class ***is*** a struct, then I could be strung up.  I've changed it to reflect both attitudes.  And what's to stop me from getting the double value of an object?

Answer (score -3):

Dont put objective C objects in structs.  Thats why Obj C supports classes.  You are coding C.

Comment: the thing thats confusing me is I want to create an array of object that contain the variables initalised in the class.. I had planned to just make a struct of variables then use the struct in the array.. how can i do this without a struct

Comment: Classes are contained by classes in objective C not structs.

Comment: I guess then the thing confusing me is how do I create an array of the classes that contain the variables.

Comment: Classes are just structs, albeit with more fancy compiler nonsense.  And what's wrong with coding in C?  I can write an NSString or an NSCFString, and it don't make a gal-durn difference to the compiler (with proper casting).

Comment: Clearly this is not the intent of the question.

Comment: Its pretty clear that if you knew C or objective C either that you would not be asking this question.  So I assumed that you are trying to mix obj C pointers and C pointers because you dont understand objective C constructs.  If you are an advanced programmer trying to mix C and obj C pointers, I think you will be advanced enough to find that documentation.  I was trying to help you with objective C.  In OBJECTive C, Objects contain other objects, structs are not typically used.  The ARC error you got was there for a reason.