# __unsafe_unretained and release with ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I **must** use a union containing a class pointer, but with ARC on, and as very well explained here: [__unsafe_unretained NSString struct var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857117/unsafe-unretained-nsstring-struct-var) you have to set the field `__unsafe_unretained`.

That means, if I understand it well, you must manage yourself its lifecycle.

For example:

```
typedef union FOO {
    char                                    __char;
    __unsafe_unretained NSMutableArray *    __array;
    __unsafe_unretained BarClass *          __bar;
}
```

If I do something like:

```
FOO * foo = malloc(sizeof(FOO));
foo.__bar = [[BarClass alloc] init];
... // I have fun with foo.__bar
[foo.__bar release] // this was before ARC and does not work anymore
free(foo);
```

How do I release `foo.__bar`? Because with ARC I cannot call `release`or `autorelease` anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `__bridge` cast and `CFRelease`:

```
CFRelease((__bridge void *)foo->__bar);
```

Some other notes:

1. Don't use the names `__char`, `__array`, and `__bar`.  All identifiers that begin with two consecutive underscores are reserved by the C standard.
2. You need to retain the object too, before the end of the statement that creates it, because at the end of that statement, ARC will release it.  The easiest way to do that is by abusing `CFBridgingRetain`:

   ```
   foo->__bar = (__bridge id)CFBridgingRetain([[NSObject alloc] init]);
   ```
3. You might be better off just turning `FOO` into an Objective-C class so that it can hold strong references.

Comment: technically correct but slightly hackish for my taste... as I said in my answer I'd just hold an add. strong pointer to it and be done with it :D

Answer (score -1):

I would hold an additional strong pointer to it, then you dont have to worry at all about releasing it.

```
BarClass *myStrongBar = [[BarClass alloc] init];

FOO * foo = malloc(sizeof(FOO));
foo.__bar = myStrongBar;
... // I have fun with foo.__bar
free(foo);
```

Comment: Where should he put that strong pointer if he's creating lots of these, and they outlive the function they're created in?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it is something I cannot do, as I am using it within generated code. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: @robmayoff agreed... that'd be bad ^^