# Initialize struct from NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct, nsarray

I'm trying to implement KD Tree in an app I build and the current example is something like this:

```
struct kd_node_t {
    int trapID;
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};

struct kd_node_t wp[] =
    {
        {1, {2, 3}}, {1, {5, 4}}, {1, {9, 6}}, {1, {4, 7}}, {1, {8, 1}}, {1, {7, 2}}
    };
```

What i'm trying to do is dynamically putting an array in the struct instead few like the example.
Any ideas how shall I do that?

**EDIT:**

I realize the question should be different --> How can I initialize this specific struct from NSArray data?

Comment: Why do you want to use instances of `NSArray`? C has the ability to put arrays of dynamic size into a structure. There are at least two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
struct kd_node_t {
    NSArray *myArray
};

kd_node_t myStruct;
myStruct.myArray = [newArray retain];
```

It should work.

Comment: Just note that this will not compile if you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857117/unsafe-unretained-nsstring-struct-var

This can help for ARC based applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC then defining a `struct` with an `NSArray *` field is non-trivial, but can be done if you are prepared to use `__unsafe_unretained` references.

It is not clear from your question that you need to use a `struct` for some reason. If you are doing it to obtain a "lightweight" structure then a methodless-class can be used:

```
@interface KD_Node : NSObject
{
   int trapID;
   NSArray *x;
   KD_Node *left, *right;
}
@end

@implementation KD_Node
@end
```

Apart from allocation, where a call to `malloc()` (or friend) is replaced by `[KD_Node new]`, using a `KD_Node *` is just like using a `struct kd_node_t *` - the fields (instance variables) are referenced using the `->` operator. There is a slight storage overhead compared to a straight `struct`, but you get to use your `NSArray *` without issue. (Of course you can add properties and/or methods later if you wish as well.)

HTH