# Why does NSObject's "isMemberOfClass:class" specify __unsafe_unretained in XCode's autocompletion?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

The vague overview is that I'm writing a method in an `NSArray` Category that will take a `Class` and filter an Array down to elements that are members of that class.  Something like:

```
@implementation NSArray(filter)
-(NSArray*)objectsOfClass:(Class)aClass {
   NSMutableArray *ret = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
   for (id obj in self)
       if ([obj isMemberOfClass:aClass])
          [ret addObject:obj];

   return [NSArray arrayWithArray:ret];
}
@end
```

Sooo, with that out of the way, on to my question.  NSObject.h shows that isMemberOfClass: has the following signature:

```
 -(BOOL)isMemberOfClass:(Class)aClass;
```

When I type this method in XCode, the autocompletion hints a method signature that looks like:

```
 [self isMemberOfClass:(__unsafe_unretained Class)]
```

My questions are:

1) Why the discrepancy between the method prototype in NSObject.h and XCode's autocompletion?
2) In my own method (shown at the start of the this question), should I include the `__unsafe_unretained` modifier?  If so, why?  If not, why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absence of an explicit ownership qualification one is inferred; this is usually `__strong` but in the case of `Class` it is `__unsafe_unretained`. This makes sense as `Class` objects are immortal and need not be memory managed by your code.

So Xcode is just making the implicit explicit and you do not need to do this yourself.

Comment: I still struggle to understand the difference between Class objects and other objects used as method parameters. According to [Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html): 1) `id`, `Class`, `NSFoo *` etc are all "retainable object pointer types", and 2) in general ARC does not perform retain/release operations when passing a retainable pointer as an argument to a function. - So what do you mean with "this is usually __strong but in the case of Class it is __unsafe_retained"? (I don't want to criticize, just trying to understand.)

Comment: @MartinR - Look at section 4.4 of the reference you quoted, it talks about inference there. Consider: if you pass, say an NSArray to a method and that method stores it into an instance variable then ARC (a) infers the ownership of the instance variable as `__strong` and (b) will assert ownership (retain) the passed argument when it stores it. However as *all* objects of type `Class` are immortal ARC never needs to do any management of ownership, and the ownership qualifier that means "leave me alone" is `__unsafe_unretained`, so for `Class` variables that is inferred rather than `__strong`.

Comment: The new Clang/ARC documentation is even more explicit: In "4.4.2 Indirect parameters": "if T is const-qualified or Class, then it is implicitly qualified with __unsafe_unretained; otherwise, it is implicitly qualified with __autoreleasing."