# Objective C Types as parameter

Tags: objective-c

Okay I am not asking HOW to get a parameter when calling a method or something.

I want something like this:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithType:(TYPE)type {

//do something

}
```

and executed like this:

```
[self doSomethingWithType:int];
```

or

```
[self doSomethingWithType:BOOL];
```

How can I make a parameter of a method/function that has a type as parameter? I mean any type.. :)

I dont want to make a int parameter, I want to make a int-type parameter, where you write the objective c type as parameter and not a value or variable :)

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is possible for non-class types. Objective-C is C, and types like `int` don't have any runtime representation.

Comment: Type is only a concept for the compiler (parser?) to follow and understand the code.  Unlike Classes which are actually objects in Objective-C, I doubt native variable types have any meaning outside the compiler.

Comment: It might be helpful to give more detail about what you're trying to do with that type so people could make alternate suggestions about how you might accomplish that.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if I understand your intention correctly, but Objective-C has a class "Class".

```
-(void)doSomethingWithType:(Class)type {
    //do something
    //for example, create an instance of this type:
    id object = [[type alloc] init];
}
```

And you can call it like so:

```
[objectOfMyClass doSomethingWithType: [SomeObjectiveCType class]];
```

It won't work with primitive types though. I mean BOOL, int, float, etc. Objective-C classes only.
Hope, that it will help. Sorry if that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried this method and this works like a charm! :) Thanks @FreeNickname! **BUT** what about memory issues? Is there any special consideration which should take in to account for passing Class types? I ask it because of xCode hint on using `__unsafe_unretained Class`

Comment: @KiNG, I'm glad I could help :) As for your question, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243003/why-does-nsobjects-ismemberofclassclass-specify-unsafe-unretained-in-xcode). There is a small conversation there. And it even has a [link to the documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters) :) Rewriting it is a bit too long for a comment, but shortly: there is nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Thanks @FreeNickname :) I was a C# and previously Delphi developer, and to be honest, I am not still comfortable with Memory Management systems in Objective-C and all that weak and strong stuff! :p

Comment: @KiNG, thank you too :) I didn't know about this until you asked :) I don't know if you read this, but manual memory management is rather well described in this paper: [Advaned memory management programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/articles/MemoryMgmt.html). I think it's good to understand the basics, even though ARC rules the land nowadays. By the way, [Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226).

Comment: @KiNG, These manuals are rather short and explain principles and conventions of memory management. There is [another paper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) about CoreFoundation. But I don't know if it's up-to-date. I haven't worked with CoreFoundation with ARC yet.

Comment: Thanks @FreeNickname :) I've added the guides to my kindle for further reading.

Answer (score 6):

Types are not [first-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578872/about-first-second-and-third-class-value) in C or Objective-C, so you can't pass them to functions.

Objective-C code generally represents them as a `char *` with something like `@encode`. So, for example:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithType:(char *)encodedType {
    NSLog(@"Got type %s", encodedType);
}

[self doSomethingWithType:@encode(int)];
```

You can see what `@encode` does in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html).

An alternative is to use a macro (rather than method) which can take arbitrary source text as a parameter to create new code. For example:

```
#define MY_MACRO(SYMBOL, TYPE) DoSomething(#SYMBOL, (TYPE *)&SYMBOL)
```

Which you'd use like:

```
MY_MACRO(foo, int);
```

Which would be equivalent to the code:

```
DoSomething("foo", (int *)&foo);
```

The "#" before SYMBOL in the macro means "make a string out of this". Note that there are *lots and lots* of gotchas when writing macros; I highly recommend googling around for a good primer on them first.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the docs I linked at the end there, you'll see that `"i"` corresponds to an `int`. Do you just want the *name* of the type, as a string?

Comment: I want to use the type. Like I have this code: MSHookFunction(((TYPE*)MSFindSymbol(NULL, "__SYMBOL")),(TYPE*)$__ SYMBOL,(TYPE**)&old__SYMBOL); and its lots of code duplication if I do that for several symbols and types, therefore I want a function that gets the TYPE as a parameter to use it in the code. so I dont have to check the type, simply use the code once in a function and then call the function like startSomething(int, "SYMBOL");

Comment: @xCoder I've added another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apple frameworks typically use `@encode`. The format defined by apple can even describe arrays of primitive types. Pros - pretty standard. Cons - you have to add code that encodes the type before calling the method and add decoding into your method.
2. Have a separate method for every type you need. Cons - a lot of methods. Pros - easily readable code, easily usable code.
3. A macro instead of a method. Macros can take any parameter, including type name. Cons - code difficult to read, pros - short code, easily usable code.

However, none of the solutions is perfect. If you need something like this, in most situations  it is only caused by a very poor design.