# runblock retain self reference cause memory dealloc issue

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction, retain-cycle

Here is my code:

```
ship.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(5), completion: {
    self.ship.flyStraight()//retain self
})
```

After several days googling for the memory issues, finally I found that I had a self retain in this block. When I create the new scene before the block has run, the deinit function won't be called because the reference in the block.

I have to write in this way in my game, and what can I do to avoid this issue. What did you with code like this?

Comment: sorry for my poor English, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The Swift documentation has a section about ["Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57) ...

Comment: Can you confirm that `deinit` is not called? since 'self' does not have a reference to the block (no strong reference cycle) wouldn't the block get reallocated when the action finishes?

Comment: ^ Deallocated not reallocated (sorry typo, too late to edit)

Comment: @Okapi  "When I create the new scene before the block has run" This is why the deinit won't be called. After the block finished, deinit will be called.

Comment: @MartinR  You can edit your comment and post an answer. I added `[unowned self] in` to my code and everything looks fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who got the same issue.
I changed my code to :

```
ship.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(5), completion: {
        [unowned self] in
        self.ship.flyStraight()        
    })
```

Use `[unowned self] in` in your block won't add a strong reference to self.

Thanks for Martin's link:  ["Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57)

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254588/swift-arc-and-blocks)