# Cocos2d 1.0.1 issue. "Expected property attribute before ..."

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Just start to learning Cocos2d and getting errors in Xcode 4.3.3 (4E3002). Problem in the defining of properties and synthesize statements in .h and .m files. Screens:

http://uaimage.com/image/b3cef723

http://uaimage.com/image/59b25425

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the out-of-date LLVM GCC, most likely because this is the default setting for cocos2d 1.0.1 projects. LLVM GCC doesn't recognize the `strong` keyword (the equivalent for LLVM GCC is `retain`).

Change the Compiler setting under Build Settings of the target to "Apple LLVM Compiler 3.x".

[See also this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584152/getting-expected-a-property-attribute-before-strong-when-compiling-an-arc-fi)