# Expected property attribute before "strong"

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

Am a newbie to `iOS`. Am getting the errors for the `@property` line,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *text;
```

using `Xcode 3.2`, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you use strong for this property? Use this: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text;` instead.

Comment: It does not work too. Expected property attribute before "weak"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584152/getting-expected-a-property-attribute-before-strong-when-compiling-an-arc-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strong` is using in ARC, it's first seen in iOS 5, in Xcode 3.2, you can use `retain`, or update Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

From [ARC docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html),

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5.

Upgrade your OSX and/or Xcode to latest or use manual memory management instead.

**Word of advice**: Starting Feb 2014, [Apple insists](https://developer.apple.com/news/) (Read: *Make Your Apps Work Seamlessly with iOS 7*) that all applications submitted to Appstore must be developed using latest Xcode and optimized for iOS7. Advisable to upgrade your dev environment

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`Strong` property is related to ARC which is only supported from **Xcode 4.2**. See this [apple's release note.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html)

Update you xcode to this.
To convert your project to ARC enable by `choose Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC`

**Note:**

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

`strong`, `weak` etc are supported in LLVM compilers. And you have Xcode 3.2 mostly running GCC compiler. Hence this token in unrecognized there.

You need to use `retain` instead of `strong`. Also if you are using `weak` replace it with `copy`.

*Also, use `weak` for Outlets.*

> GCC remains the default compiler for Xcode 3 but with the release of
>   Xcode 4 the default compiler for new projects has changed to LLVM-GCC.

You can also set the compiler for your Xcode and/or project. For more see [Compilers for Xcode.](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/21/compiler-options-in-xcode-gcc-or-llvm.html)