# I'm having linking warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm doing a tab button on my navigation bar of my (FirstViewController),when i press button it should pop me the view controller(FlipsideViewController).i had this linker error message

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipsideViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is my code in

```
#pragma mark - Flipside View 
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller 
{ 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
} 
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender 
{ 
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    controller.delegate = self; 
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: #pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

Comment: The problem is not in FlipsideViewController but rather in the way that you include it into the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker warning has nothing to do with the code. It's just that the compiler couldn't find the class `FirstViewController` which you'll have to add to compile sources:

[image]

Comment: thanks i just add the file in my compile sources.but i had this error – 
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;...........the current deployment target does not support automated_weak references

Comment: It seems you have ARC turned on. Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893038/how-do-i-replace-weak-references-when-using-arc-and-targeting-ios-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing FlipsideViewController file compiled or linked into code.
Check: 
`Project->Build Phases->Compile Sources` if you have there FlipsideViewController file.

[image]

Also check if its included into project.

Comment: thanks i just add the file in my compile sources.but i had this error

Comment: @synthesize delegate = _delegate;...........the current deployment target does not support automated_weak references

Comment: Does your target is iOS verson below 5.0 ? If yes, disable ARC in build settings project>Build Settings->Objective-C Automatic ReferenceCounting set NO and contnue development with retain/release/autorelease memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Your FlipsideViewController implementation is missing from the files to be linked.

Check your project settings by tapping on the Top-Node within the Project Navigator -> *Build Phases* -> *Compile Sources*.

[image]

`FlipsideViewController.m` must be listed. If it is not, use the + Symbol on the bottom to add it.