# How to fix memory leaks in ARC enabled iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

i'm developing an iPhone project in which i enabled ARC, and when i run my project with instruments so many places it is showing 100% leak for ex:

```
-[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondPage animated:YES]; //100% leak

[self loadXML];//100% leak
```

even if i make secondPage object as nil after pushing and in viewDidUnload the leak docent get resolved. How can i solve these leaks?Any help is appreciated in advance.Thank You.

Comment: For trivia, see this question I asked: [What kind of leaks does Objective-C's automatic reference counting (in Xcode 4.2) not prevent/minimize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-objective-cs-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-4-2)

Comment: You'll need to post some more code though. It's not clear at all what you're doing pushing these controllers or loading anything.

Comment: How do you know that the leak comes from -[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondPage animated:YES]; /

Answer (score 2):

The Leaks instrument (in Instruments) will tell you exactly what was leaked, where it was created, record the stack, and (optionally) record every reference count operation. Learning to use it proficiently is highly recommended.

Comment: Where is this leaks instrument?

Comment: @JimThio in the 'Memory' group when you launch Instruments, or type 'leaks' in the library's search field.

Comment: How do I launch instruments? Can you have screen shot.

Comment: Oh I found it. The menu doesn't say instrument. It doen't tell me the exact code leak occurs though.

Comment: THe menu doesn't call it instrument. They call it profile or something. It's after the window open I saw instrument.