# Develop opengles games in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-1.1

it's very boring question to everyone but i did't get any idea of my question that'y am asking here,if you know please guide me

I have year of experience in iOS application development not in game development,now i have plan to start opengl game development to iOS,but i have lot of confusion and questions in my mind,here i listed below please guide me.

1.Where to start game development?
2.no need develop game with help of any other framework e.g:cocos2d like?  it possible to develop game only in opengl with sort time period?
3.how much time take develop opengles game(normally)?
4.pratically opengles is hard or easy?
5.which language is best for opengles development c++ or objective-c?
6.if there any website to explain opengles development to beginners with partially example?
7.in opengl which is best 1.1 or 2.0 ?

Thanks to advance..

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Question of the form, "How do I start?", "What tools/language should I use?", or "Which is better?" are not acceptable on this Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very nice tutorials available for learning opengl-es you can learn them here :

1. You can check this [learning opengl-es ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482327/learning-opengles-2-0-on-ios)
2. There is a nice video tutorial by Brad Larson here : [opengl-es video tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)
3. You can read these tutorial by Ray Wenderlich here : [Opengl-es tutorial ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)
4. There is a nice tutorial series here : [ios opengl-es lessons](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/ios_lesson_01__setting_up_gl_es/44001/)
5. check a great opengl-es tutorial series [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html).

Hope it helps you.