# In which situations can't we simply rely on Automatic Reference Counting?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I've heard that in some situations developers must still be aware of basic memory management rules. So when is knowledge about ARC not enough to develop iOS apps?

(I know the mem management basics but a friend does not and wants to begin development).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of leaks does Objective-C's automatic reference counting (in Xcode 4.2) not prevent/minimize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-objective-cs-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-4-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that understanding what's going on under the hood is always helpful, especially in cases like this where ARC uses naming conventions to make everything work correctly.

But to directly answer your question: it can't handle retain cycles automatically and it only works with objects, so if you use any CoreFoundation methods you'll still have to worry about memory management.

Also, if you use any third party or open source libraries then they might not be ARC compatible (though you can mix ARC and non-ARC code in one executable).

Answer (score 0):

dontWatchMyProfileless,

tl;dr: Tell you friend to just use ARC and the rest will sort itself out.

Long form:

I teach beginning iOS programming at my local community college. I bring this up not because I am an expert in ARC but that I've taught beginners modern Objective-C.

The real question is when should a professional iOS programmer learn all of the intricacies of iOS memory management?

In my fall 2011 class, I was able to have students ignore memory management issues for most of the semester. It then emerged when needed as students started using the C-based APIs -- Core Graphics, GCD etc. I introduce it when the students have to start __bridge casting.

ARC really helped the students learn Cocoa Touch. Memory management emerged as an advanced feature, which it now is. In particular, I like toggling ARC on & off to show people memory leaks.

Now, go get your friend coding.

Andrew