# Why is my app full of memory leaks after migrating to ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

After migrating my app to ARC using the migration tool and resolving all pending issues a quick test in the Allocation instrument revealed that **pretty much anything I do in the app is leaking memory**.

It's a pretty big app and migration took 2 hours to complete (including checking every change which I did - all of them looked fine!)

I checked all the compiler flags twice to make sure ARC is really enabled for every file and on the project level.

Previously to migrating to ARC my app was totally fine. There was absolutely no heap growth when taking Heapshots by repeating the same action multiple times. It was 100% leak-free, there was no abandoned memory. It was perfect. Now it's one huge leaking thing like if there was no tomorrow.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: +1, as this is something I'm considering doing with one of my current projects in development (it's not too big, so I think turning the ARC flags on would be a good educational experience for me). I wonder if using Instruments (and the object alloc template) would be useful in your particular case?

Comment: Be sure to make a backup first. Fortunately I did. But I wasted several hours for the migration. Probably it's better to migrate by hand one file after another and keep testing in Instruments. Of course this can take a few days of work so I don't think it's viable for existing projects. There should be no reason why Instruments wouldn't be useful or would display misleading information.

Comment: @openfrog No. "Be sure to use a good [D]VCS." I recommend Hg (or Git). :)

Comment: Keeping strong references and not nil-ing them? Pretty hard to say without knowing what is leaking.

Comment: @openfrog: What David said.  Can we see some code in the area where instruments is complaining?

Comment: Kinda confirms my suspicion that ARC is not quite ready for prime time.

Comment: @HotLicks - I strongly disagree. I'm now using it in at least three applications in production, and these applications are better of for it. The issues that people are encountering are not due to bugs in the implementation, but people adjusting to how this mode of memory management works. While you could wait and let others expand the documentation and examples around this, the technology itself is robust right now.

Comment: @BradLarson -- It seem like it's at least questionable as to how practical it is to convert a large pre-existing app, vs writing to ARC from scratch.

Comment: @HotLicks - The two largest applications I converted over were 19,000 and 24,000 lines of code, with the last one being done manually because the ARC migrator doesn't yet work for GC Mac applications. While there's more busywork in stripping out old code in a non-ARC application, you're going to need to be aware of the same best practices even if you're starting fresh with an ARC-enabled application. I figure I'll have to learn this at some point, so I might as well get the benefits now.

Comment: Well, lessee:  The three projects I've most recently worked with are 14,812, 58,531, and 55,356 LOC.  I'm not going to be in any hurry to convert any of those.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't shown any code here to highlight parts of your application that are causing objects to accumulate in memory, so it's hard to provide a specific answer to your situation. However, there are some broad suggestions that I can provide based on my experience in migrating several projects across on Mac and iOS.

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388601/19679), I describe in detail several areas of memory management that you'll still need to watch out for under automatic reference counting. The primary concerns here are retain cycles and Core Foundation objects (or other non-Objective-C memory allocation).

Given that you had an application which did not accumulate memory on repeat actions before and was cleanly ported through the ARC migration tool, retain cycles are more likely the problem than improper bridging, etc. with Core Foundation. The migration tool tends to highlight problematic areas with Core Foundation and catch those before they become an issue. How to deal with them may be tricky, but you at least know they're there.

Retain cycles can be subtle bugs to track down. Look for delegates that are set using strong instance variables or properties, rather than weak or unsafe-unretained ones. Examine your use of blocks or block-based notification observers, because they can hold on to references to the objects that create them (particularly in the case of the observers) and create cycles. Check for objects further down a navigation hierarchy that use strong references to point to ones higher up.

Use Instruments to track down the specific objects that are accumulating via the Leaks and Allocations tools. In the latter, use heap shots between repeated actions to see which objects are created and still alive after each pass. You should also be able to identify where those objects are allocated, hopefully leading back to what's grabbing an incorrect strong reference.

The Leaks instrument has a new retain cycles detector, which can be seen by going to the lower panel and changing the "Leaks" popup to "Cycles & Roots". This doesn't catch everything, but it can help.

I've now moved multiple projects on Mac and iOS to ARC, including Mac applications that had been using GC, and in each case the applications have been better off for it. The process has exposed bugs that I had missed for years in my memory management, cut on average ~3% of my project code, and has led to some significant performance increases in my previously garbage collected Mac applications (I haven't benchmarked my iOS ones yet).