# How does ARC determine whether to use retain or copy?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

As LLVM compiler with ARC option add retain, copy,release and autorelease for us automatically, but how does ARC determine whether to use retain or copy?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-automatic-reference-counting-in-objective-c-not-prevent/6388601#6388601     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work

Comment: @janusfidel Thanks for those, but it maybe not the answer I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC doesn't add `copy`, that's still your responsibility if you need copies. It only manages `retain` and `release` for you. If you manually `copy` something though it knows that you get a new object that it will have to release at some time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in following docs (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#meta)

> Automatic Reference Counting implements automatic memory management
>   for Objective-C objects and blocks, freeing the programmer from the
>   need to explicitly insert retains and releases. It does not provide a
>   cycle collector; users must explicitly manage the lifetime of their
>   objects, breaking cycles manually or with weak or unsafe references.

Also you can go through the discussion of this thread - [How does the new automatic reference counting mechanism work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385212/how-does-the-new-automatic-reference-counting-mechanism-work)