# Memory Leak with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

```
+(void)setup {
    UIImage* spriteSheet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mySpriteSheet.png"];
    CGRect rect;
    animation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfFramesInSpriteSheet];
    int frameCount = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < numberFrameRowsInSpriteSheet; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberFrameColsInSpriteSheet; col++) {
            frameCount++;
            if (frameCount <= numberOfFramesInSpriteSheet) {
                rect = CGRectMake(col*frameHeight, row*frameWidth, frameHeight, frameWidth);
                [animation addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(spriteSheet.CGImage, rect)] ];
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Compiled the above code with ARC enabled. The Analyze tool reports a possible memory leak since imageWithCGImage:: returns UIImage with count +1, then reference is lost. Leaks Instrument reports no memory leaks at all. Whats going on here?

Furthermore, since ARC prohibits use of manually using `release` ect, how does one fix the leak?

Thanks to anyone who can offer any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ARC does not manage C-types, of which CGImage may be considered.  You must release the ref manually when you are finished with `CGImageRelease(image);`

```
+(void)setup {
    UIImage* spriteSheet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mySpriteSheet.png"];
    CGRect rect;
    animation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfFramesInSpriteSheet];
    int frameCount = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < numberFrameRowsInSpriteSheet; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberFrameColsInSpriteSheet; col++) {
            frameCount++;
            if (frameCount <= numberOfFramesInSpriteSheet) {
                rect = CGRectMake(col*frameHeight, row*frameWidth, frameHeight, frameWidth);
                //store our image ref so we can release it later
                //The create rule says that any C-interface method with "create" in it's name 
                //returns a +1 foundation object, which we must release manually.
                CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(spriteSheet.CGImage, rect)
                //Create a UIImage from our ref.  It is now owned by UIImage, so we may discard it.
                [animation addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image]];
                //Discard the ref.  
                CGImageRelease(image);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see the accepted answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-automatic-reference-counting-in-objective-c-not-prevent/6388601#6388601

Comment: "The create rule says that any C-interface method with "create" in it's name returns a +1 foundation object, which we must release manually." - doh! Of course. Thanks CodaFi! Appreciated!

Comment: @Z.O. No problem.  The create rule is actually a little hard to find in the docs, but it's very important when dealing with Apple's C-Interfaces.  [Here it is](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) (along with the get rule).

Comment: @nielsbot If we're getting technical, then CG- prefixed structures aren't a part of Core Foundation, so I called them foundation types in line with what the documentation calls them.  They follow the exact same rules though, so the terms are interchangeable.

Comment: If the docs call them foundation types I guess we should use that. Too bad we also have Foundation, however.

Answer (score 3):

None of the core foundation data structure is dealt with ARC. Many a times this creates a problem. In these case we have to manually release the memory.