# imageWithCGImage leaks according to instrument

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, cgimage, alasset

Below is a screenshot from instrument app.

[image]

Is there any explanation what is wrong with that line ?

Answer (score 1):

ARC does not manage C-types, of which CGImage may be considered. You must release the ref manually when you are finished with CGImageRelease(image); 
[found the answer hire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540087/3593011)