# GPUImage not releasing memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

Memory keeps building up and not releasing with GPUImage. If I change the filter on a UIImage, the old filter memory is never released

My code:

Have a UIImageView as a class property:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *capturedImageView;
```

I apply the filter like so

```
GPUImageFilter filter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];
UIImage *filteredImage = [filter imageByFilteringImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage.CGImage]];
[filter removeAllTargets];
[filter endProcessing];
```

I then set the imageView.image property to the filtered image

```
self.capturedImageView.image = filteredImage;
```

Now at any time I might change the filter (based on what a user selects (ie an instagram like filter list)). When I do change the filter I just use the code above (but alloc a different filter)

I don't understand why memory keeps building up? I tried setting my imageview.image property to nil and GPIFilter to nil but that does nothing

Comment: If you are not using ARC, trying releasing the filtered image, and then setting the filtered image to something else.

Comment: I'm using ARC, tried setting filter to nil with no luck

Comment: Most likely its because you are constantly creating new filters.  Have you tried creating them only once and then passing around the filters pointers on demand instead of creating a filter each time?

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. Not sure why that would help. Would also be inefficient to create a bunch of filters which may or may not get used but that regardless of the point. That tactic doesn't work :(

Comment: Its helpful because you will only have an instance of the gray filter compared to multiple instances of a gray filter if the user constantly switches between a gray filter and a non-gray filter.

Comment: Since the instance only lives locally inside a method it should release itself right? Its not a class property

Comment: Are you experiencing this on device?

Comment: @Andrea yes on both the device and simulator

Comment: What is the class of `myImage` in your example ? This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656934/imagewithcgimage-leaks-according-to-instrument) states that `imageWithCGImage` might be linked to your memory leak. What does instrument shows ?

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior when using Swift as well as using Objective-C.