# UIImage memory leak issue in ARC

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

We used below code to set image in image view,

```
@autoreleasepool {
    UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImgTitle" ofType:@"png"]]];
    }
```

Instruments shows memory leak in above two lines. We checked through Xcode 5.0.1 to iOS7.

Anyone please suggest to resolve that issue.

Comment: Can i knew reason for write code into the @autoreleasepool??

Comment: We used UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
                         [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                         [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
                         @"ImgTitle" ofType:@"png"]]]; code alone. To reduce memory leak we put the code inside the autoreleasepool, now memory leak percentage ll be reduced, but still leak happens.

Comment: have you used this, [pool drain];

Comment: @Ramdy with \@autoreleasepool, he don't need to drain the pool.

Comment: Under ARC, this code shouldn't leak any memory, please paste your Instrument snapshot.

Comment: Please share the exact message thrown by the analyzer

Comment: Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6388601/468724

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
@autoreleasepool
{
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
                         [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                         [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
                         @"ImgTitle" ofType:@"png"]]];
}
```

to

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
                             [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                             [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
                             @"ImgTitle" ofType:@"png"]]];
```

After using the titleView you can set it to nil to handle memory as below.

If project is ARC enabled, use

`titleView=nil;`

If not,

```
titleView release];
titleView=nil;`
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me your code is showing

`Dead Store : Value stored to 'titleView' during its initialization is never read`

Which makes sense too.
There is no memory leak warning